# How to make mind flayer mind control better

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew, monster-design

I feel like the Mind Flayers ability to control minds (a once per day Dominate Monster) is almost universally thought of as underpowered, especially given the description of Mind Flayers. How could a DM make it more powerful and more deserving of the Uber Mind controller status?

Comment: Perhaps a few citations would help here, such as the assertion that the Mind Flayer's ability to control minds is "almost universally thought of as underpowered" and what you mean by the referral to the Mind Flayer description (are you referring to their enslavement of other races?)

Comment: Even beyond citations, the question could use some clarification on "more powerful and more deserving of the Uber Mind controller status". Changing the ability via DM fiat to "dominate any thinking creature indefinitely, for free, an unlimited number of times per day" would fit that, for example, but may not be the sort of answer you're looking for. How would you evaluate answers?